# How to set up IntelliJ IDEA to use Java 10 non-LTS version for project development?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-10

I'm looking to switch the default SDK of my project in IntelliJ IDEA to Java 10 specifically. However, when I navigate to the download JDK option within IntelliJ, I notice that there's no vendor providing the **non-LTS version of Java 10**. Could someone guide me on how to configure IntelliJ IDEA to utilize Java 10, even though it's a non-LTS version?

[image]

[image]

My expectation is to set the current project SDK to java10,
I even tried to change Language level, doesn't seem working [image]

I am not able to download JDK-10 from oracle.com
And tried with multiple vendors, didn't find JDK-10 specifically (non-LTS), Hence "Add JDK" option is of no use too.

Comment: Support for Java 10 ended back in September 2018, why would you still want to use it?

Comment: Can you download outside of Intellij, then add Java 10 to the SDKs section instead?

Comment: I need that for a presentation demo to show differences between Java 10 and 11 specifically to interns

Comment: In any case, as OneCriketeer says, you should be able to manually install a Java 10 SDK, and then add that in IntelliJ. Those first two screenshots are from a popup specifically for **downloading** a JDK from within IntelliJ. If you source your JDK elsewhere, you should be able to add it yourself.

Comment: Given your interns probably started using Java *after* release of Java **17** (September 2021), why care about the differences in older versions...

Comment: Some of the several JDK vendors may provide an archive of old versions. Vendors include: Adoptium (Eclipse Foundation), Azul Systems, Amazon, Microsoft, Oracle, Red Hat, IBM, BellSoft, SAP, and more.

Answer (score 3):

### *SDKMAN!*

I recommend using [sdkman](https://sdkman.io/) for downloading or switching between SDKs from your choice of multiple JDK/JRE vendors.

And then use the ***Add New SDK*** approach descibed by stefano-riffaldi.

Answer (score 1):

Simply download an archive file (.zip/.tar/whatever) of JDK you want from the website of the vendor you choose (Eclipse, Amazon, Oracle, whatever), unpack it where you want, open ID, right click on your project, choose `Open Modulue Settings (F4)`, then under `Platform Settings` open `SDKs` an click on `+` labeled `Add SDK` on top, choosing yours

[image]